# How do I make a transparent brick texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, transparency

I have a grid set up with a brick texture, and I want to have only the green mortar showing up, so I tried setting the alpha for color 1 and color 2 to 0, but the bricks are still opaque. How can I fix this? Should I even be using a brick texture for this?[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Fac" output it is alpha value. Connect it to Alpha input

[image]

Note, that if you are using EEVEE, you should also select transparency mode (Blend mode) in material settings:

[image]

Comment: worked like a charm =)

Comment: Woah a light theme user, almost didn't recognize Blender there for a second